# Активность и база данных Android Studio

Tags: android, база-данных

Передо мной стоит задача: есть две Активити, главная отображает данные из базы данных, на другой мы добавляем данные в базу данных.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне нужно чтоб такое сделать?

Comment: Прочитать в Гугле любой туториал по базам данных в андроид. На startandroid есть про Room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую посмотреть Android codelabs -> *Android Room with a View* https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0
все очень просто, без воды, шаг за шагом. Если будете просто копировать код думаю все получится - хороший пример для начинающих и затрагивает много моментов. Пример который там показан очень подходит к вашему описанию.